# "Uncatching" an exception in python

Tags: python, exception

How should I "rethrow" an exception, that is, suppose:

- I try something in my code, and unfortunately it fails.
- I try some "clever" workaround, which happens to also fail this time

If I throw the exception from the (failing) workaround, it's going to be pretty darn confusing for the user, so I *think* it may be best to rethrow the original exception (?), *with the descriptive traceback it comes with* (about the *actual* problem)...

Note: the motivating example for this is when calling `np.log(np.array(['1'], dtype=object))`, where it [tries a witty workaround and gives an `AttributeError`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1611) (it's "really" a `TypeError`).

One way I can think of is just to re-call the offending function, but this seems doged (for one thing theoretically the original function may exert some different behaviour the second time it's called):
*Okay this is one **awful** example, but here goes...*

```
def f():
    raise Exception("sparrow")

def g():
    raise Exception("coconut")

def a():
    f()
```

Suppose I did this:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    # attempt witty workaround
    g()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c76b7509b315> in <module>()
      3 except:
      4     # attempt witty workaround
----> 5     g()
      6

<ipython-input-2-e641f2f9a7dc> in g()
      4
      5 def g():
----> 6     raise Exception("coconut")
      7
      8

Exception: coconut
```

Well, the problem doesn't really lie with the coconut at all, but the sparrow:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    # attempt witty workaround
    try:
        g()
    except:
        # workaround failed, I want to rethrow the exception from calling a()
        a() # ideally don't want to call a() again
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e641f2f9a7dc> in <module>()
     19     except:
     20         # workaround failed, I want to rethrow the exception from calling a()
---> 21         a()  # ideally don't want to call a() again

<ipython-input-3-e641f2f9a7dc> in a()
      8
      9 def a():
---> 10     f()
     11
     12

<ipython-input-1-e641f2f9a7dc> in f()
      1 def f():
----> 2     raise Exception("sparrow")
      3
      4
      5 def g():

Exception: sparrow
```

Is there a standard way to deal with this, or am I thinking about it completely wrong?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299756/python-reraise-recatch-exception

Comment: Have you tried the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos care to put an answer together using it?

Comment: Your intuition that the original exception should be re-raised is correct: that's what's done in Java try-with-resources (equivalent of Python `with` statements), but Java also adds the secondary exception as a "suppressed" exception, via `Throwable#addSuppressed`, so you actually can get a *tree* of exceptions! See [Who decides what exceptions get suppressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11603300/2025416).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to make it appear to the end user that you never called `g()`, then you need to store the traceback from the first error, call the second function and then throw the original with the original traceback. (otherwise, in Python2, bare raise re-raises the second exception rather than the first).  The problem is that there is no 2/3 compatible way to raise with traceback, so you have to wrap the Python 2 version in an `exec` statement (since it's a `SyntaxError` in Python 3).

Here's a function that lets you do that (I added this to the `pandas` codebase recently):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    def raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback=Ellipsis):
        if traceback == Ellipsis:
            _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
        raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
else:
    # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3
    exec("""
def raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback=Ellipsis):
    if traceback == Ellipsis:
        _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    raise exc, None, traceback
""")

raise_with_traceback.__doc__ = (
"""Raise exception with existing traceback.
If traceback is not passed, uses sys.exc_info() to get traceback."""
)
```

And then you can use it like this (I also changed the Exception types for clarity).

```
def f():
    raise TypeError("sparrow")

def g():
    raise ValueError("coconut")

def a():
    f()

try:
    a()
except TypeError as e:
    import sys
    # save the traceback from the original exception
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        # attempt witty workaround
        g()
    except:
        raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
```

And in Python 2, you only see `a()` and `f()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    a()
  File "test.py", line 28, in a
    f()
  File "test.py", line 22, in f
    raise TypeError("sparrow")
TypeError: sparrow
```

But in Python 3, it still notes there was an additional exception too, because you are raising within its `except` clause [which flips the order of the errors and makes it much more confusing for the user]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    g()
  File "test.py", line 25, in g
    raise ValueError("coconut")
ValueError: coconut

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
  File "test.py", line 6, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    a()
  File "test.py", line 28, in a
    f()
  File "test.py", line 22, in f
    raise TypeError("sparrow")
TypeError: sparrow
```

If you absolutely want it to look like the `g()` Exception never happened in both Python 2 and Python 3, you need to check that you are out of the `except` clause first:

```
try:
    a()
except TypeError as e:
    import sys
    # save the traceback from the original exception
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    handled = False
    try:
        # attempt witty workaround
        g()
        handled = True
    except:
        pass
    if not handled:
        raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
```

Which gets you the following traceback in Python 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    a()
  File "test.py", line 28, in a
    f()
  File "test.py", line 22, in f
    raise TypeError("sparrow")
TypeError: sparrow
```

And this traceback in Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    raise_with_traceback(e, tb)
  File "test.py", line 6, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    a()
  File "test.py", line 28, in a
    f()
  File "test.py", line 22, in f
    raise TypeError("sparrow")
TypeError: sparrow
```

It does add an additional non-useful line of traceback that shows the `raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)` to the user, but it is relatively clean.

Comment: Maybe at the time of writing this answer there was 'no 2/3 compatible way to raise with traceback' but now in [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) there is a function six.reraise that does pretty much what @jeff shows here.

Comment: you're right! I didn't know that was in six (and it looks like it was actually added to the library in 2010!).  It's implemented in a pretty similar way too

Answer (score 8):

Here is something totally nutty that I wasn't sure would work, but it works in both python 2 and 3. (It does however, require the exception to be encapsulated into a function...)

```
def f():
    print ("Fail!")
    raise Exception("sparrow")
def g():
    print ("Workaround fail.")
    raise Exception("coconut")
def a():
    f()

def tryhard():
    ok = False
    try:
        a()
        ok = True
    finally:
        if not ok:
            try:
                g()
                return # "cancels" sparrow Exception by returning from finally
            except:
                pass

>>> tryhard()
Fail!
Workaround fail.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in tryhard
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in a
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
Exception: sparrow
```

Which is the correct exception and the right stack trace, and with no hackery.

```
>>> def g(): print "Worked around." # workaround is successful in this case

>>> tryhard()
Fail!
Worked around.

>>> def f(): print "Success!" # normal method works

>>> tryhard()
Success!
```

Comment: If you don't want to encapsulate it in a function, the concept also works with `break` from a finally, although I was surprised to learn that `continue` in a finally is actually a syntax error!

Comment: Um, I get `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` when trying it outside a function? (both py2 and 3)

Comment: Yes, you need to enclose the whole outer try block in some kind of gratuitous context like `for _ in range(1):`. I didn't say it was pretty.

Comment: @morningstar You call it nutty that you used `finally` as it was meant to be... and which I totally overlooked. +1

Comment: Yup, the `finally` clause is exactly the solution to this question: “When an exception has occurred in the `try` clause and has not been handled by an `except` clause (or it has occurred in a `except` or `else` clause), it is re-raised after the `finally` clause has been executed.” Tutorial: [Defining Clean-up Actions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), Reference: [The try statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

Answer (score 6):

Ian Bicking has a nice [primer on re-raising](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/).

As a corollary, my rule is to only catch Exceptions that the code knows how to deal with. Very few methods actually hit this rule. For example, if I'm reading a file and an IOException is thrown, there is very little that method could reasonably do.

As a corollary to that, catching exceptions in "main" is reasonable if you can return to a good state and you don't just want to dump the user out; this only obtains in interactive programs.

The relevant section from the primer being the update:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        g()
    except:
        # If this happens, it clobbers exc_info,
        # which is why we had to save it above
        import traceback
        print >> sys.stderr, "Error in revert_stuff():"
        # py3 print("Error in revert_stuff():", file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exc()
    raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
```

In python 3, the [final raise could be written as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838224/python3-re-raising-an-exception-with-custom-attribute):

```
ei = exc_info[1]
ei.filname = exc_info[0]
ei.__traceback__ = exc_info[2]
raise ei
```

Comment: It does seem like a bit of a hack... but this is the *only* working answer so far :)

Comment: Ian used to be a bit of a fixture around here; he's certainly spent his time in the trenches. I have no idea why his SO rep has crashed.

Comment: This method (using the saved `exc_info()`) is about the only way to make things work after you've clobbered the previous exception info.  (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760267/re-raise-python-exception-and-preserve-stack-trace)  It needs modification for Python 3.x: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838224/python3-re-raising-an-exception-with-custom-attribute

Comment: @torek I've updated answer to include that too for convenience.

Comment: @torek, Python 3 doesn't need to save exc_info.  Just `raise`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 (specifically tested on 3.3.2), this all works better, there's no need for saving `sys.exc_info`.  Don't re-raise the original exception within the second exception handler.  Just note that the 2nd attempt failed and raise the original in the scope of the original handler, like so:

```
#!python3

try:
    a()
except Exception:
    g_failed = False
    try:
        g()
    except Exception:
        g_failed = True
    raise
```

Python 3 output correctly raising "sparrow" and showing traceback through `a()` and `f()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x3.py", line 13, in <module>
    a()
  File "x3.py", line 10, in a
    f()
  File "x3.py", line 4, in f
    raise Exception("sparrow")
Exception: sparrow
```

However, the same script on Python 2 incorrectly raising "coconut" and only showing `g()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x3.py", line 17, in <module>
    g()
  File "x3.py", line 7, in g
    raise Exception("coconut")
Exception: coconut
```

Here are the modifications to make Python 2 work correctly:

```
#!python2
import sys

try:
    a()
except Exception:
    exc = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        g()
    except Exception:
        raise exc[0], exc[1], exc[2] # Note doesn't care that it is nested.
```

Now Python 2 correctly shows "sparrow" and both `a()` and `f()` traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x2.py", line 14, in <module>
    a()
  File "x2.py", line 11, in a
    f()
  File "x2.py", line 5, in f
    raise Exception("sparrow")
Exception: sparrow
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and it's confusing because you use a different example than the one I gave (which makes it look like it does).

Comment: That's the exact code and output I used...guess it works better in Python 3.  Your code with just a simple `raise` works too.  No need to save the `exc_info`.

Comment: Ah! It is a python 2 thing... yet another reason to port. Weird.

Comment: Is a nice idea, would be cool to know if there was a way to do it like this in python 2!

Comment: I think what @msw found is the way.  The `sys.exc_info` has to be saved.

Comment: @AndyHayden, I updated my answer with your example and both Python 2 and 3 examples.

Comment: Very nice. Only a little upset it doesn't work for both python 2 and 3 :)

Comment: Nice answer; it can be done a little more cleanly inside a function (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Capture the error in your `except` clause, then manually re-raise it later. Capture the traceback, and reprint it via the `traceback` module.

```
import sys
import traceback

def f():
    raise Exception("sparrow")

def g():
    raise Exception("coconut")

def a():
    f()

try:
    print "trying a"
    a()
except Exception as e:
    print sys.exc_info()
    (_,_,tb) = sys.exc_info()
    print "trying g"
    try:
        g()
    except:
        print "\n".join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
        raise e
```

Comment: This still raises a coconut... I don't want to reraise the last exception, but the one before that. ?

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you could save the exception (via `except`) and re-raise it directly, then?

Comment: Here, I rewrote my answer.

Comment: That only shows the last line of the exception, i.e. you lose the traceback, and that points to `raise e`. :(

Comment: Hmm. `sys.exc_info()` will give you a traceback object inside the `except` clause. I think you'd need to print it out yourself. Doable, but I've not worked with them before.

Comment: OOH, maybe you could replace the info in the second `except` clause, then let Python find the "new" one?

Comment: Hmm @msw uses `sys.exc_info()`... was hoping for a simple way really! :)

Comment: Ooh! There's a new `traceback` module since the last time I played with Python. This time I got really close. Try it.

Comment: Still the same issue with where it raises, and that it only shows one  thing in the traceback. Surely traceback is the right module... :(

Comment: @jpaugh, you just needed to use [raise with 3 expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) from [Ian's primer via @msw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17001551/1020470). Also you can use the [`sys.last_traceback`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.last_traceback) attribute instead of dumping the 1st and 2nd outputs of `sys.exc_info()` and use [`traceback.print_tb(tb)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.last_traceback) instead of `traceback.format_tb()` but you don't need `traceback` module at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, within a function, this can be done in a very slick way, following up the answer from @Mark Tolonen, who uses a boolean. You can't do this outside a function because there's no way to break out of the outer `try` statement: the function is needed for `return`.

```
#!python3

def f():
    raise Exception("sparrow")

def g():
    raise Exception("coconut")

def a():
    f()

def h():
    try:
        a()
    except:
        try:
            g()
            return  # Workaround succeeded!
        except:
            pass  # Oh well, that didn't work.
        raise  # Re-raises *first* exception.

h()
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uc.py", line 23, in <module>
    h()
  File "uc.py", line 14, in h
    a()
  File "uc.py", line 10, in a
    f()
  File "uc.py", line 4, in f
    raise Exception("sparrow")
Exception: sparrow
```

...and if instead `g` succeeds:

```
def g(): pass
```

...then it doesn't raise an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    1/0  # will raise ZeroDivisionError
except Exception as first:
    try:
        x/1  # will raise NameError
    except Exception as second:
        raise first  # will re-raise ZeroDivisionError
```

Comment: Then I lose the rest of the traceback (it only gives back the last line, raise first).

Comment: I know this is demo code, but you never want to catch Exception as it could be a MemoryError which is quite difficult to cope with or `RuntimeError` which mostly means the interpreter is dying and anything you do is likely wrong.

Comment: @msw that's my "mistake" :)